# How to extract numpy array values from within a gdb session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, gdb

When using gdb with python extensions on a Python3 process using numpy and attempting to print values, I get things like:

```
(gdb) py-print y
local 'y' = <numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7f80dcc53350>
(gdb) p * (PyArrayObject *)0x7f80dcc53350
$12 = {ob_base = {ob_refcnt = 12, ob_type = 0x7f81838f7180}}
```

How do I print the actual values inside `y`?

Answer (score 0):

[Numpy Ndarrays](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L1453-L1457)

This might help you.

Comment: Thanks - I figured out that I need to be using `PyArrayObject_fields` rather than `PyArrayObject`, so now I am mostly set - except I am unsure whether `PyFloatObject` is a legal way to access a `numpy.float 64` or not.. (As in:
(gdb) py-print h
local 'h' = <numpy.float64 at remote 0x7f80dccd4270>
(gdb) p * (PyFloatObject*)0x7f80dccd4270
$34 = {ob_base = {ob_refcnt = 3, ob_type = 0x7f8183909600}, ob_fval = -nan(0x8000000000000)}